# Unformatted output in operator <<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I have a class that contains decoded video frames. I would like my decoder to use an `output_iterator` to write those frames to different targets. In order to support writing directly to a file, I want to overload `operator <<` for my decoded frame class (for use with `ostream_iterator`). The problem is, that `operator <<` is meant to be used for formatted output, but I want to do unformatted output with it. Are there any pitfalls to be considered? Is there another solution, or is it OK to just go with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::basic_ostream` is indeed mainly to be used for formatted output. (I say "mainly" because it does have a method for unformatted output. But that's not accessible through output iterators.) For unformatted output, use a [stream buffer iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/ostreambuf_iterator/).

Answer (score 0):

use the unformatted out put function like getchar, fgets

Comment: in c++ some unformated output function are usefull just try it . it will work